# Should I separate files in After Effects for different part of a Premiere Pro project?

Tags: after-effects, premiere

I am new to these two software and I want to do a little video for the promotion of the next show of a musical troupe. They want to recruit new people.

I have done an effect for the intro in after effects, I want to add another one effect for the end to tell about what kind of people they want to recruit.

Should I do both in one same after effects project or shoud I do several production in one project ?

I guess I should do several projects but I'm really not sure as far as I am new and found noting about it on the Internet ...

Answer (score 1):

You can do both. I myself have used both methods. However, my recommendation would be to do each shot in its own project. Here are my thoughts on both methods.

Doing it all in one project makes things faster, because you don't have to create a new project for every shot you have. However, the problem with this is that the project gets really convoluted. It means you have to be super organized to keep the project tidy. But even when you do that, if you need to come back to the project, it usually takes you a bit of time to get your head around what is what and where can I find this specific item, especially if you are using a lot of precomps in the project.

Doing each shot in its own project keeps things really simple, because you know that everything here belongs to this shot and that's it. You can quickly figure out what is happening, especially if the project is organized and tidy.

Of course, I am assuming that you are doing simple effects on each shot. If you are doing major vfx or compositing work on your shots, then you should definitely create a new project for each shot, because that project will get convoluted due to the scale of the job you are doing. So you shouldn't be making it even bigger with adding other shots to it.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the **replace clip with After Effects composition** feature in Premiere it will automatically add the new comp to whatever After Effects project is currently open. I usually use this when I'm adding things like titles and FX to vieo that I'm editing, so everything ends up in the same project.

If you keep the project organised I find this isn't a problem, in fact it's easier if you want to re-use assets, or use templates. E.g. things like lower thirds I will make using one pre-comp as the background with the text for each one on its own layer, so I can just swap it out for each one.

Comment: So for a project your recommend one project with several compositions if it is organised, isn't it ?

Comment: Well, I wouldn't say one is better, but if you have AE and Premiere open then this is what will happen.